# Saving grep's result to a variable

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following command:

```
pvs /dev/sdb | grep failed
```

The result is for example:

```
/dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 1073676288: Input/output error
/dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 1073733632: Input/output error
/dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

Now I want to save that result to a variable:

```
STATUS=`pvs /dev/sdb | grep failed`
```

However, when I read the content, it is empty:

```
echo $STATUS
```

I tried redirecting it to a file:

```
`pvs /dev/sdb | grep failed` > /tmp/hdd-status
```

Same result, the file remains empty.

Comment: It's pvs sending failed messages to stderr? If so, try: `STATUS=``pvs /dev/sdb 2>&1 | grep failed``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The messages that you see appear to be *standard error* messages, not *standard output*.  You can read more about redirection [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).

As such, you'd need to merge `STDERR` with `STDOUT` before piping the output to `grep`:

```
STATUS=`pvs /dev/sdb 2>&1 | grep failed`
```

Moreover, the other form of [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) instead of using backticks is somewhat more readable:

```
STATUS=$(pvs /dev/sdb 2>&1 | grep failed)
```

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or \.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

Answer (score 5):

This is because what you see comes from `stderr` and you are catching just `stdin`.

Just redirect stderr to stdin like this:

```
2>&1
```

So that your variable is defined as follows:

```
STATUS=$(pvs /dev/sdb 2>&1 | grep failed)
```

Note also I am using the `$()` syntax, which is commonly preferred over ``. Basically, because it allows you to nest them.

---

See another example:

We `ls` two files: `a` and `hello`. First exists but `hello` does not:

```
$ ls a hello
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
a
```

We store the output:

```
$ v=$(ls a hello)
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
```

And the error is not stored:

```
$ echo "$v"
a
```

But it is if we redirect:

```
$ v=$(ls a hello 2>&1)
$ echo "$v"
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
a
```